# How to make a terminal split view?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I work with different machines and want to have one window of terminal split into two or three. To see at once what happens on different machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Check out GNU screen and tmux, both allow splitting a terminal either horizontally or vertically (or both). I prefer tmux myself, though I also use screen from time to time.

The other option would be to use Terminator instead of Terminal, this splits the window itself and is arguably easier to use.

The nice thing about screen/tmux is you can ssh to a remote machine and then run them there so you only have a single connection but still have multiple shells.

Comment: Found it here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do spilt-screen terminals use terminator. I use it all the time
sudo apt-get install terminator